# Bug: Text box wrapping inside the header menu

Tags: discussion, bug, design

### Bug: Showing mouse pointer in the menu when entering any value with scrolling down.

When I scroll down with any text in  answer box or comment box. The text box went inside the menu. at this if am typing any text. the mouse pointer is displaying in menu.

I have attached two images for this bug. thanks

### Image 1:

[image]

### Image 2

[image]

**Note**. You can pay any amount to me for raise this bug :P. Just for fun

Comment: I can't reproduce this, and it does in fact sound like a browser bug. What browser and operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Goto [Edit Profile & Settings](https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/current) and select the tab **Preferences** under SITE SETTINGS.

Tick the option *Disable stickiness*. Problem solved. Here is a picture with red freehand circle:

[image]

You can pay any amount to me for getting rid of this bug for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I'll pay you after getting the offer letter from stack overflow. be wait :p

Comment: However the position should be fixed

Comment: _You can pay any amount to me for getting rid of this bug for you._ - You have no soul.